# Possible to determine how many rasters selected for a single GetParameterAsText()?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I wrote a script for ArcMap Desktop 10.5.1. The purpose of the tool is to buffer a feature to 1000ft, mosaic rasters together, and clip the raster to the buffered polygon. It works flawlessly; however, I don't need to run mosaic when I only have one raster but it runs it anyways and takes a while to finish.

My questions is this, is it possible to know how many rasters were selected by the user for a single GetParametersAsText()? If so, and the user only selects one, it will skip the mosaic step.

[image]

```
# imports
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# retrieval of input parameters from environment
inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # set scratch workspace
mosaicBE = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
##mosaicInt = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# --- MAIN CODE STARTS HERE ---

# Initiate start
arcpy.AddMessage("\nGetting started...\n")

# -- 1000FT BUFFER --
if arcpy.Exists("bufferedLake"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Buffer already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("bufferedLake")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Buffered layer deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Buffering...")
lakeBuffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inFC, "bufferedLake", "1000 FEET")
arcpy.AddMessage("Buffering completed!\n")

# extracts raster extent coordinates (x,y max and min)
desc = arcpy.Describe(lakeBuffer)
xmin = str(desc.extent.XMin)
ymin = str(desc.extent.YMin)
xmax = str(desc.extent.XMax)
ymax = str(desc.extent.YMax)

arcpy.AddMessage("X Min: " + xmin)
arcpy.AddMessage("Y Min: " + ymin)
arcpy.AddMessage("X Max: " + xmax)
arcpy.AddMessage("Y Max: " + ymax + "\n")

extentList = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
joined = ' '.join(extentList)

# -- MOSAIC BARE EARTH RASTERS --
if arcpy.Exists("newBE"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Mosaic already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("newBE")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth mosaic deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Mosaic of Bare Earth started...")
mosaicBareEarth = arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(mosaicBE, arcpy.env.workspace, "newBE", "#", "32_BIT_FLOAT", "#", "1", "#", "#")
arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth mosaic completed!\n")

### -- MOSAIC INTENSITY RASTERS --
##if arcpy.Exists("scratch.gdb/newInt.tif"):
##    arcpy.AddMessage("Intensity mosaic found, deleting...")
##    arcpy.Delete_management("scratch.gdb/newInt.tif")
##    arcpy.AddMessage("Intensity mosaic deleted")
##arcpy.AddMessage("Mosaic of Intensity started...")
##mosaicIntensity = arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(mosaicInt, arcpy.env.workspace, "scratch.gdb/newInt.tif", "#", "#", "#", "1", "#", "#")
##arcpy.AddMessage("Intensity mosaic completed!\n")

# -- CLIPS RASTERS TO BUFFERED LAKE --
if arcpy.Exists("scratch.gdb/clippedBE"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Clip already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("scratch.gdb/clippedBE")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth clip deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping Bare Earth mosaic to lake polygon...")
clipMosaicBE = arcpy.Clip_management(mosaicBareEarth, joined, "scratch.gdb/clippedBE", lakeBuffer, "-9999", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping completed!\n")

##if arcpy.Exists("scratch.gdb/tif"):
##    arcpy.AddMessage("Intensity clip found, deleting...")
##    arcpy.Delete_management("scratch.gdb/tif")
##    arcpy.AddMessage("Intensity clip deleted")
##arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping Intensity mosaic to lake polygon...")
##clipMosaicInt = arcpy.Clip_management(mosaicIntensity, joined, "scratch.gdb/tif", lakeBuffer, "-9999", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
##arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping completed!\n")

# confirms end of operation
arcpy.AddMessage("Finished\n")
```

Comment: Please place code in the question as code (ASCII text, formatted via `{}`). It's less likely that others will look at external images (bad security practice), and if you want help, you shouldn't make volunteers retype your code.

Comment: Create mosaic dataset once and work with it. Not mosaic to new raster.

Comment: Thanks Vince for the tip! And FelixIP, I will try that thank you!

Comment: Well that was easy! I used Mosaic_management instead of MosaicToNewRaster, and created a GetParameterAsText(4) for Target Raster below the 'Select Bare Earth Raster Dataset(s)' and just selected the same raster for each when only one was use. Processed much faster! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question. That way you are likely to gain rep and unlock site tools.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @PolyGeo, clearly I'm new to StackExchange so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [helpful suggestion by @FelixIP](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293207/possible-to-determine-how-many-rasters-selected-for-a-single-getparameterastext#comment470213_293207), I replaced 'MosaicToNewRaster' with 'Mosaic_management' and added a GetParameterAsText(3) for selecting the Target raster. See below for an updated script:

```
# imports
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# retrieval of input parameters from environment
inFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # set scratch workspace
mosaicBareEarthInput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
mosaicBareEarthTarget = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
##mosaicInt = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

# --- MAIN CODE STARTS HERE ---

# Initiate start
arcpy.AddMessage("\nGetting started...\n")

# -- 1000FT BUFFER --
if arcpy.Exists("bufferedLake"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Buffer already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("bufferedLake")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Buffered layer deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Buffering...")
lakeBuffer = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(inFC, "bufferedLake", "1000 FEET")
arcpy.AddMessage("Buffering completed!\n")

# extracts raster extent coordinates (x,y max and min)
desc = arcpy.Describe(lakeBuffer)
xmin = str(desc.extent.XMin)
ymin = str(desc.extent.YMin)
xmax = str(desc.extent.XMax)
ymax = str(desc.extent.YMax)

arcpy.AddMessage("X Min: " + xmin)
arcpy.AddMessage("Y Min: " + ymin)
arcpy.AddMessage("X Max: " + xmax)
arcpy.AddMessage("Y Max: " + ymax + "\n")

extentList = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
joined = ' '.join(extentList)

# -- MOSAIC BARE EARTH RASTERS --
if arcpy.Exists("newBE"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Mosaic already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("newBE")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth mosaic deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Mosaic of Bare Earth started...")
mosaicBareEarth = arcpy.Mosaic_management(mosaicBareEarthInput, mosaicBareEarthTarget)
arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth mosaic completed!\n")

# -- CLIPS RASTERS TO BUFFERED LAKE --
if arcpy.Exists("scratch.gdb/clippedBE"):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Clip already exists, deleting...")
    arcpy.Delete_management("scratch.gdb/clippedBE")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Bare Earth clip deleted")
arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping Bare Earth mosaic to lake polygon...")
clipMosaicBE = arcpy.Clip_management(mosaicBareEarth, joined, "scratch.gdb/clippedBE", lakeBuffer, "-9999", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping completed!\n")

# confirms end of operation
arcpy.AddMessage("Finished\n")
```